# How to make Nivo Slider Responsive

Tags: jquery, slider, responsive-design, nivo-slider

I am using NivoSlider in WordPress and implemented some responsive css to the theme, I have fixed the width & height of the images and background size in Nivo Slider also but its displaying correct size only once and afterwards its displaying big images in the slider.

Here is the link to the site : [Website](http://rjmultimedia.in/innovatus/)

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was officially announced by nivo slider that it is responsive, Here is announcement.

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/2012/05/30/the-nivo-slider-is-responsive/

Demo :

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/responsive-demo/

Answer (score 1):

css

```
 #nivoSlider, #nivoSlider img{width:100%;height:auto !important}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
    <div id="nivoSlider" class="nivoSlider">
       <img src="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for that css, works with Nivo Slider in drupal as well.