# How can to responsive Nivo slider with content ?

Tags: html, css, nivo-slider

I am a newbie to web development.I just tried to add Nivo slider to my content.I added that.But the problem is when I try to transfer my template to `mobile devices(320px)` it won't work properly.The background picture got responsiveness, but content in the slider won't be responsive.How come I fix this problem.I tried many ways but won't work.Here is my Nivo slider HTML code...

```
<section id="wrapper">
    <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">     
    <img src="assets/img/01.jpg" data-thumb="assets/img/01.jpg" alt="" />    
    <img src="assets/img/02.jpg" data-thumb="assets/img/02.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption1" />     
    <img src="assets/img/01.jpg" data-thumb="assets/img/01.jpg" alt="" />     
    <img src="assets/img/02.jpg" data-thumb="assets/img/02.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption2" /> 
</div> 

<div id="htmlcaption1" class="nivo-html-caption responsive_slider">   
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam officiis incidunt, iusto sit repellendus vel consequuntur, consequatur unde possimus sapiente expedita aut! Magnam necessitatibus corporis fugit impedit illum hic corrupti.
    </p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary mt-3" href="#">Read More&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>         
</div>

<div id="htmlcaption2" class="nivo-html-caption responsive_slider">     
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam officiis incidunt, iusto sit repellendus vel consequuntur, consequatur unde possimus sapiente expedita aut! Magnam necessitatibus corporis fugit impedit illum hic corrupti.
    </p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary mt-3" href="#">Read More&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>         
</div>     
</div>
</section>
```

And here is my CSS code...

```
.slider-wrapper { 
    width: 100%;    
    margin: 0 auto;    
}

.nivo-caption {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 52%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50%;
}



.slider_button_1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;     
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;    
}

.slider_button_1:hover {
    background: #0069A8;
}
```

I want to response the slider with that's content.Is there anyway.

Thanks from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

CSS

```
#nivoSlider, #nivoSlider img{width:100%;height:auto !important}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
    <div id="nivoSlider" class="nivoSlider">
       <img src="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference: [How to make Nivo Slider Responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156708/how-to-make-nivo-slider-responsive)

Comment: But the problem is what should I enter in the ribbon class.pls explain that.And if you can pls give the hole markup

Comment: Can you add  demo in jsbin or jsfiddle  i will help you integrate this

Answer (score 0):

I have found one reference for you. Here is the reference link: [Nivo Slider - Awesome jQuery Slider Plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/nivo-slider.html)

Comment: I saw that earlier.The slider is responsive.But want to respond the slider with content.